# Does ListActivity extends Activity?

Tags: java, android, slidingmenu

I'm developing an Android app with a Sliding menu.

I have created a custom class to use in a `ListFragment` to show menu items:

```
public class MenuItem
{
    /**
     * Title to show on sliding menu.
     */
    private String title;
    /**
     * Activity to start when user select a menu item.
     */
    private Class<Activity> activityClass;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public Class<Activity> getActivityClass() {
        return activityClass;
    }
    public void setActivityClass(Class<Activity> activityClass) {
        this.activityClass = activityClass;
    }
}
```

This is my `ListFragment`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.com.msx.R;
import com.com.msx.adapters.MenuAdapter;
import com.com.msx.menu.MenuItem;

public class MenuFragment extends ListFragment
{
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_list, null);
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ArrayList<MenuItem> menuItems = getMenuItems();

        MenuAdapter adapter = new MenuAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.menu_row, menuItems);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    /**
     * Get menu items to show on Sliding menu.
     * @return
     */
    private ArrayList<MenuItem> getMenuItems()
    {
        String[] titles = {
                getActivity().getString(R.string.menu_item_my_lovers),
                getActivity().getString(R.string.menu_item_my_friends),
                getActivity().getString(R.string.menu_item_geo_sex_locator),
                getActivity().getString(R.string.menu_item_sex_affinity),
                getActivity().getString(R.string.menu_item_messages),
                getActivity().getString(R.string.menu_item_statistics)
        };

        // TODO: Add icons for each menu item.
        ArrayList<Class<? extends Activity>> activities = new ArrayList<Class<? extends Activity>>(titles.length);
        activities.add(SelectFriendsActivity);

        ArrayList<MenuItem> items = new ArrayList<MenuItem>(titles.length);
        for(int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++)
        {
            MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
            item.setTitle(titles[i]);
            // TODO: Set icon.
            items.add(item);
        }

        return items;
    }
}
```

And now, I'm trying to fill `ListFragment` list's adapter with a custom `ArrayAdapter`. But when I try to do this:

```
ArrayList<Class<Activity>> activities = new ArrayList<Class<Activity>>(titles.length);
activities.add((Class<Activity>)SelectFriendsActivity.class);
```

I get these two compiler errors:

```
Cannot cast from Class<SelectFriendsActivity> to Class<Activity>    
SelectFriendsActivity cannot be resolved to a type
```

If I do this:

```
ArrayList<Class<? extends Activity>> activities = new ArrayList<Class<? extends Activity>>(titles.length);
activities.add(SelectFriendsActivity.class);
```

I get this compiler error:

```
The method add(Class<? extends Activity>) in the type ArrayList<Class<? extends Activity>>
 is not applicable for the arguments (Class<SelectFriendsActivity>)
```

`SelectFriendsActivity` has this prototype:

```
public class SelectFriendsActivity extends android.app.ListActivity
```

But if I change SelectFriendsActivity.class for MainActivity.class (which extends Activity) **it works**!

**What's happening?**

Comment: Declare `List<X> l = new ArrayList<X>()`, not `ArrayList<X> l = ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why [am I] having these errors?

Because `Activity.class` is not equal to `SelectFriendsActivity.class`.

You should declare a `List<Class<? extends Activity>>` instead of an `ArrayList<Class<Activity>>`.

Witness this code snippet:

```
    final List<Class<? extends Number>> list
        = new ArrayList<Class<? extends Number>>();

    // Both Integer and BigDecimal extend Number
    list.add(Integer.class);
    list.add(BigDecimal.class);
```

Similarly, in `MenuItem`, your getter/setter/instance member should return/have as an argument/be of type `Class<? extends Activity>`. Suggestion: drop the setters, build the `MenuItem` directly, this way you can make it immutable. Currently, your `MenuItem` class is *not* thread safe because of these blasted setters. Javabeans in general are not thread safe.

> Is there a better way to know which Activity I have to start when user selects a menu item?

Not sure since you don't show enough code. Why do you return a class and not a fully constructed instance, for starters?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work. I have updated my question with details about what's happening now.

Comment: Uhm, you really don't show enough code since that should work alright. What is this `ListActivity` class?

Comment: It's an `android.app.ListActivity`.

Comment: Are you sure you import `android.app.Activity` and not something else?

Comment: Does SelectFriendsActivity have to extend ListActivity? Try extending as Activity and see if it works.

Comment: I have updated my question with more code: I have added the whole class where I get that error.

Comment: If I change `SelectFriendsActivity.class` for `MainActivity.class` (which `extends Activity`) it works!

Comment: Check your import in `SelectFriendsActivity`. The problem is most probably in there.

Comment: On `SelectFriendsActivity` the import is `import android.app.ListActivity;`.

Comment: That should definitely work. What compiler/IDE are you using? Eclipse?

Comment: Add to your answer that I haven't import `SelectFriendsActivity` and I mark it as an answer. The another error, `SelectFriendsActivity cannot be resolved to a type` was the key. Maybe, I haven't understand you. Sorry.

Comment: Uuh, if you haven't imported it, the error should have been totally different :/ Ahwell, you got it working eventually, so all is fine ;)